# Google SSO Testing - Cypress: Getting 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: request, cypress, google-sso

When I run the following Google SSO test in Cypress, I get the following

> 401 error message:"error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Unauthorized".

The user, Jackie Chan, is able to log on via Google, manually, but for some reason, this test is failing in Cypress.  After looking at it, my teammate and I think it may have to do with the port Cypress gives us when we turn it on.  Does anyone know how to overwrite the port Cypress provides, and instead give Cypress the port we want? That would be the next route we would take, unless someone knows what the issue could be? Thank you.

```js
   //Test
    describe("Google", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit("/");
      });
    
      it("Google SSO is working", () => {
        cy.request({
          method: "POST",
          url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
          body: {
            grant_type: "refresh_token",
            client_id: Cypress.env("MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"),
            client_secret: Cypress.env("MY_GOOGLE_SECRET"),
            refresh_token: Cypress.env("MY_GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN"),
          },
        }).then(({ body }) => {
          const { id_token } = body;
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: It seems you are not passing the proper credentials in the body I would double check on that first, since it gives 401.

Answer (score 2):

To find out more information about the failure, turn off `failOnStatusCode` and check the body error data.

```js
cy.request({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
  body: {
    grant_type: "refresh_token",
    client_id: Cypress.env("MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"),
    client_secret: Cypress.env("MY_GOOGLE_SECRET"),
    refresh_token: Cypress.env("MY_GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN"),
  },
  failOnStatusCode: false
})
.its('body')
.then(body => cy.log(body.error, body.error_description))
```

For example

> **log**  invalid_client, The OAuth client was not found.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this a problem with Cypress port, I think is something with your credential, so I advise you to double check yours MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, MY_GOOGLE_SECRET and MY_GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN, print those credentials in your logs and check in the Cypress Logs if everything is correct. But, if you really want to change Cypress port you can just put in your cypress.json or cypress.config the variable `port` and pass the port number you want to use:

```
{
   "port": 3030
}
```

Or just run headless in a different port with:

```
cypress run --port 3030
```